# Kind of a Number Pattern

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

[image]

I found this problem in a highschool Reasoning olympiad in India.

Comment: A few simple answers come up, but they require ignoring some of the numbers. Looking at only the numbers in the squares produces an obvious answer that is in the list of answers. Looking at only the top-left circle and the square produces a different answer within the list... but both of those feel too simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer is

> A

For a couple of reasons...

> First there is a sequence in the centre squares of 30, 34 and then 38

And

> Secondly, we get the number in the square by taking the sum of the numbers in circles multiplied together... Plus 4... Editing... So the first number 30 = 1x9 + 3x2 + 1x3 + 1x8 + 4. And the second number 34 = 2x1 + 3x7 + 1x5 + 2x1 + 4.... And so for the last box we find 2x2 + 2x8 + 1x8 + 1x6 + 4 = 38, which is answer A